# Heap corruption while dynamically allocating an array of arrays in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-corruption

I am trying to create an array of pointers to store 6 array's with varying amount of dimensions and types. I use this in a much bigger program, I tried to make the easiest/smallest possible representation of the problem, just bare in mind that in the actual program there are a lot more variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MCD 5
const uint64_t layer_s[] = {    /* The start of each layer */
  0,
  1,
  1 + 4,
  1 + 4 + pow(4, 2),
  1 + 4 + pow(4, 2) + pow(4, 3),
  1 + 4 + pow(4, 2) + pow(4, 3) + pow(4, 4),
  1 + 4 + pow(4, 2) + pow(4, 3) + pow(4, 4) + pow(4, 5)
};

const uint64_t l_size[] = { /* Size of each layer */
  1, 4,
  pow(4, 2), pow(4, 3),
  pow(4, 4), pow(4, 5)
};

void
func(void *a_p, uint_fast32_t obj_pos, uint_fast32_t nrn_pos,
     uint_fast8_t l_shifted, uint_fast8_t l_remaining)
{

  void *(*a) = a_p; /* Array array's */
  uint32_t(*neuron_a)[layer_s[MCD + 1]] = a[0]; // Neuron array [Objects][Neurons]
  uint16_t(*str_a)[layer_s[MCD + 1]] = a[1];    // Strength array [Objects][Neurons]
  uint8_t(*TS_a)[layer_s[MCD + 1]] = a[2];  // Total score array [Objects][Neurons]
  int8_t(*prox_a) = a[3];   // Proximity array [Objects]
  float (*prox_ang_a) = a[4];   // Proximity angle array [Objects]
  void *(*prox_obj_a) = a[5];   // Proximity object array Objects]
  uint_fast8_t i = 0;
  printf
      ("Input variables: [%d][%d] layer_shift: %d layer remaining: %d\n",
       obj_pos, nrn_pos, l_shifted, l_remaining);

  while (1) {       /* Shift every layer down by l_shifted layers */
    printf("memmove(%d, [%d][%d], %d)\n", layer_s[l_remaining - i],
           obj_pos, nrn_pos, l_size[l_remaining - i]);
    memmove(a[0] +
      layer_s[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                 1] *
      sizeof(uint32_t), &neuron_a[obj_pos][nrn_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                1] *
      sizeof(uint32_t));
    memmove(a[1] +
      layer_s[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                 1] *
      sizeof(uint16_t), &str_a[obj_pos][nrn_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                1] *
      sizeof(uint16_t));
    memmove(a[2] +
      layer_s[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                 1] * sizeof(uint8_t),
      &TS_a[obj_pos][nrn_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * layer_s[MCD +
                1] * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memmove(a[3] + layer_s[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(int8_t),
      &prox_a[obj_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(int8_t));
    memmove(a[4] + layer_s[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(float),
      &prox_ang_a[obj_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(float));
    memmove(a[5] + layer_s[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(void *),
      &prox_obj_a[obj_pos],
      l_size[l_remaining - i] * sizeof(void *));

    if (i++, i <= l_remaining) {
      obj_pos = round((double)(obj_pos - layer_s[i - 1]) / 4);  /* Go 1 layer lower */
      nrn_pos = round((double)(nrn_pos - layer_s[i - 1]) / 4);
    } else
      break;
  }
}

int main()
{

  void *(*a) = malloc(6 * sizeof *a);   /* Array of array's */

  a[0] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(uint32_t));
  a[1] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(uint16_t));
  a[2] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(uint8_t));
  a[3] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(int8_t));
  a[4] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(float));
  a[5] = malloc(layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(void *));

/* Set array's to 0 */
  memset(a[1], 0, layer_s[MCD + 1] * layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(uint16_t));
  memset(a[5], 0, layer_s[MCD + 1] * sizeof(void *));

  func(a, 1, 1, 1, 0);

/* free array's */
  return 0;
}
```

The output it gives:

```
Input variables: [1][1] layer_shift: 1 layer remaining: 0
memmove(0, [0][1], 1)
```

The expected output:

```
Input variables: [1][1] layer_shift: 1 layer remaining: 0
memmove(0, [1][1], 1)
```

Notice how the `obj_pos` changes from `1` to `0` where no code besides print functions are executed, I would expect `obj_pos` to be `1` in the second print function too.

EDIT: I've ran this program on a different computer too, here the output is correct, but the memory does still get corrupted, just a few bytes later.

I believe earlier in the programs runtime the memory heap gets corrupted, but I failed to find where. Does someone understand what causes `obj_pos` to change value between the two print functions?

EDIT 2: I am using 32 bit GCC, with an x64 CPU with 64 bit, could this cause issues between the sizes of the pointers?

Answer:

The problem was that pointer (void*) were 4 bytes in GCC and my OS was using 8 bytes per pointer, this caused the memory alignment for the array of void* to be cause heap corruption.

This is really a shame since with mingw-w32 its specified that its 32 bit GCC compiler works on 64 bit operating systems.

Comment: I see no lists here.  A list typically has a `next` pointer of some sort.  This looks like an array of arrays.

Comment: "_Does someone understand what causes `obj_pos` to change value between the two print functions?_" = undefined behaviour,, not really worth speculating about further as it could be any unexpected sequence of code/data causing `obj_pos` to get corrupted. Anyway, wrong array indexing yet again - "next" ;-)

Comment: @WilliamPursell @underscore_d I am not talking about linked lists, ```a``` is litterally just an array with the 6 pointers to each of the array's. Does this still apply?

Comment: @jenidu The title of your question mentions "array list".  Perhaps you should edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

You have set MCD to 5 but you are adding one to it when accessing layer_s. Layer_s only has 6 entries 0..5 so the value at offset 6 is undefined. This would lead to the malloc’ed memory being of unknown size and you will probably corrupt the heap when you memset your arrays to 0.

Comment: Basically right, but IMHO once they index out-of-bounds, it's not really worth speculating about why the undefined behaviour manifests the way it does - it just needs to be fixed ;)

Comment: Oh snap! That was an issue when making this example program, that isn't the problem that actually causes the problem in the post though.

Comment: @jenidu So edit your question to have corrected code that still repros the problem. And make sure you don't add any new errors, as that'll just be wasting readers' time more!

Comment: @underscore_d I did make the allocation of ```layer_s``` go up to 7, that was what you meant right, or did I miss something?